# Boost_LIBRARYDIR is set, but CMake still cannot find components using FIND_PACKAGE on windows

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Going through other questions on this topic, I think I've done all that was already mentioned.

Boost environment variables:

[image]

The library path I copied from the output of successful boost build:

```
The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    XXXXX\lib\boost_1_79_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    XXXXX\lib\boost_1_79_0\stage\lib
```

This is what I have in my CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(my-project VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX C)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
```

And the error I get looks like this:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: system filesystem unit_test_framework)
  (found version "1.79.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2377 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)
```

I can see it found boost itself, but cannot find the components I want to use. I can find them in `boost/stage/lib` and I can also see the build projects in `libs/MY_COMPONENT/build`.

Thanks to the advice in the comments, I was able to use `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` to see a discrepancy between what CMake looks for and what I have. The discrepancy is `lib` prefix that my build produces:

- `Expected:    boost_filesystem-vc143-mt-x64-1_79`
- `Actual  : libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-x64-1_79`

What do I need to do to get CMake to locate these libraries?

Comment: Run `cmake` with additional option `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON`, so it will print the exact file names, corresponding to the Boost libraries which are searched.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks a lot, it helped me to find the issue: the results of my boost build are prefixed with `lib`, but that's not what cmake expects.

Comment: No, `lib` prefixes by themselves are not a problem. They are assumed to be added automatically, like the extensions (`.lib`). Please, add to the question post full output of `Boost_DEBUG` option. (It is better to provide **exact** output, without XXX replacements. If path of your current Boost installation contains sensitive information, then install Boost to other path, adjust Boost_ROOT environment variable for that new path and run configuration again.)

Comment: On Windows `boost_` prefixed libs are import libraries for dynamic link libraries when Boost is built with dynamic linkage, `libboost_` prefixed libs are created when Boost libs are built as static libraries, which seems to be the default. Add the command `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)` before your `find_boost` command in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, delete the `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build dir and rerun your cmake command.

Comment: Just noticed the typo, it's the other way round, you need to use the command `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)` to link to Boost static libraries

Comment: @vre yes, this is the correct solution. I have set it during the configure step instead, as I don't want to enforce it for build